# Using git to push to github - current branch has no upstream then shh error

Tags: git, github, ssh, upstream-branch

I've pushed from git to github on this ssh/set up before. IT HAS WORKED.

I created a new repo on github. I set up remote - when I type git remote -v it gives back two lines starting with "origin" that have the (fetch) and (push) addresses. They're both correct, correct username and spelling.

If I type

```
git add .
git commit -m "initial commit"
git push
```

I get "fatal: the current branch main has no upstream branch. To push..."

so I try the following command it suggests (I type it exactly, maybe I need to change a bit?)

```
git push --set-upstream origin main
```

Then it says: "ssh: Could not resolve hostname github: Name or service unknown /n fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repo exists"

So I check git remote -v

It has the correct name and the ssh definitely works - I used it yesterday. I've tried re-creating the repo and changing the remote already but that didn't help.

What is wrong? What can I try next? Thanks!

Comment: Are you able to view GitHub in your browser? Try `ping github.com` to verify if you have a route. Also `dig github.com` will test if you can lookup the domain name through DNS.

Comment: I added a link at the top that has more suggestions to try. If none of those work for you, please [edit] your question to describe the result of each step that you tried. Ping me and we'll go from there.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I've tried this thread, everything except "- adding nameservers to /etc/resolv.conf fixed the issue for me!" No new errors, everything is authenticating re: ssh and Github's systems are up.

Comment: I've also tried uploading files to repo manually so there's something in it then adding a new file locally and pushing. It will stage, just won't add to repo. Exact same errors

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the things you have tried and the results of each.